# I have an issue in uploading file in laravel, how can I solve this problem?

Tags: php, laravel

I use this script to upload a file to the server using laravel.

```
$fileName = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
Storage::put('/public/uploads/'.$fileName,$request->file('file'));
$url = Storage::url('public/uploads/'.$fileName);

$fileModel = new File;
$fileModel->name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
$fileModel->file_path = $url;
$fileModel->save();
```

this code works great in local host (wamp server) but when I use it in the server, get this error:
"message": "The "" file does not exist or is not readable.",
"exception": "Symfony\Component\Mime\Exception\InvalidArgumentException",
I also tried to upload lots of know file types (png,pdf,jpeg,mp4,...). same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check for folder permission issues including the temporary folder on the server `tmp`.
2. Check the maximum upload file size: `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your server settings.

Comment: folder permission was the reason of the error. I just reset the host and It works now